# ¿Cómo puedo poner 0 ó 1 en un campo nuevo de un dataframe según el resultado de una sentencia realizada a él mismo?

Tags: python, pandas

Os comento: estoy trabajando con un dataframe `ord_df` que he rellenado a través de un sentencia sql. Estos son los datos que tengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He realizado una consulta sobre los registros del dataframe y he metido los resultado (true,false) que me da en una lista llamada `condicion`.

Aquí os pongo el código y la imagen con los resultados:

```
condicion = [(ord_df['Dia_Semana'] == 2) & (ord_df['Hora'] == '10:16:00')]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podreis ver el registro que me da el valor `True` es el **5** que es el que coincide con la condición puesta en el código.
Seguidamente, me he creado un campo nuevo dentro del dataframe el cúal he rellenado con valor **0**:

```
ord_df['Resultado'] = 0
```

Ahora lo que quisiera hacer a través de una sentencia recorrer el dataframe y con la condición que tengo, poner en el campo `Resultado` el valor **1** cuando sea verdadero.

He estado mirando por ahí y he visto la sentencia `select` de `NumPy` pero no se como utilizarla y si es la más indicada para lo que quiero hacer.

A ver si alguien me podría ayudar.

Gracias de antemano.

Charo.

Answer (score 0):

aquí os pongo un ejemplo con el resultado de la pregunta que he realizado por si alguien la necesita.

```html
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'IdActivo': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                   'Fecha': ['1990-01-02','1990-01-03','1990-01-04','1990-01-05','1990-01-08',\
                                  '1990-01-09','1990-01-10','1990-01-11','1990-01-12' ,'1990-01-15',\
                                  '1990-01-16', '1990-01-17', '1990-01-18','1990-01-19','1990-01-22',\
                                  '1990-01-23 ', '1990-01-24', '1990-01-25','1990-01-26','1990-01-29'],
                   'Hora': ['10:10:00','10:11:00','10:12:00','10:13:00','10:10:00',\
                                  '10:10:00','10:17:00','10:14:00','11:14:00','12:14:00',\
                                  '10:10:00', '10:20:00', '14:22:00','15:22:00','16:22:00',\
                                  '10:10:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00','00:00:00','00:00:00']})
def Inicio():
    numHoraDia = '10:10:00'
    numDia = 2  # para nosotros el 2 será el martes ya que le añadimos +1 al lunes que es 0 por defecto
    nomDiasSemanaHora = "  Resultado";    inpfield = "Fecha" ;    oupfield = "Dia_Semana"

    df_final = Fecha_Dia_Hora(df,inpfield,oupfield,numHoraDia,numDia,nomDiasSemanaHora)
    print (df_final)


def Fecha_Dia_Hora(df, inpfield, oupfield,numHoraDia,numDia,nomDiasSemanaHora):
    ord_df = df.sort_values(by=['IdActivo', 'Fecha'])
    ord_df[inpfield] = pd.to_datetime(ord_df[inpfield])  # Esta línea pone el campo nuevo 'inpfield' a tipo class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'
    ord_df[oupfield] = ord_df[inpfield].dt.dayofweek + 1  # Resultados: 0=Lunes, 1=Martes... 4=Viernes Le he añadido un 1 para que empiece por 1=Lunes.....
    ord_df[nomDiasSemanaHora] = np.NaN
    ord_df.ix[np.logical_and(ord_df[oupfield] == numDia, ord_df.Hora == numHoraDia), [nomDiasSemanaHora]] = '1'
    return ord_df.sort_index()

def Fin():
    print("FIN")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Inicio()
    Fin()
```

Esta es la imagen con los resultados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Saludos para todos.